# How does volume mount from container to host and vice versa work?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, persistent-storage, persistent-volumes

```
docker run -ti --rm -v DataVolume3:/var ubuntu
```

Lets say I have a volume DataVolume 3 which pulls the contents of /var in the ubuntu container
even after killing this ubuntu container the volume remains and I can use this volume DataVolume3 to mount it to other containers.
This means with the deletion of container the volume mounts are not deleted.
How does this work ? 
Does that volume mount mean that it copies the contents of /var into some local directory because this does not look like a symbolic link ? 
If I have the container running and I create a file in the container then the same file gets copied to the host path ?
How does this whole process of volume mount from container to host and host to container work ?

Comment: run `docker volume ls` to see your volumes. You are correct, they are not deleted when deleting a container. Basically when you link a volume it overlayes the folder you link to. When you link from the host the same thing happens, the folder in the container gets "overlayed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volumes are used for persistent storage and the volumes persists independent of the lifecycle of the container.

We can go through a demo to understand it clearly.

First, let's create a container using the named volumes approach as:

```
docker run -ti --rm -v DataVolume3:/var ubuntu
```

This will create a docker volume named `DataVolume3` and it can be viewed in the output of `docker volume ls`:

```
docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               DataVolume3
```

Docker stores the information about these named volumes in the directory `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` (*):

```
ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/
1617af4bce3a647a0b93ed980d64d97746878564b141f30b6110d0818bf32b76  DataVolume3
```

Next, let's write some data from the ubuntu container at the mounted path `var`:

```
echo "hello" > var/file1
root@2b67a89a0050:/# cat /var/file1
hello
```

We can see this data with `cat` even after deleting the container:

```
cat /var/lib/docker/volumes/DataVolume3/_data/file1
hello
```

Note: Although, we are able to access the volumes like shown above but it not a recommended practice to access volumes data like this.

Now, next time when another container uses the same volume then the data from the volume gets mounted at the container directory specified as part of `-v` flag.

(*) The location may vary based on OS as pointed by David and probably can be seen by the `docker volume inspect` command.

Answer (score 1):

Volumes are part of neither the container nor the host. Well, technically everything resides in the host machine. But the docker directories are only accessible by users in "docker" group. The files in these directories are separately managed by docker.

"Volumes are stored in a part of the host filesystem which is managed by Docker (/var/lib/docker/volumes/ on Linux)."

Hence volumes are like the union of files under the docker container and the host itself. Any addition on either end will be added to the volume(/var/lib/docker/volumes), not hard copy, rather something like symbol link

As volumes can be shared across different containers, deleting a container does not cascade to the volumes associated with it.

To remove unused volumes:

```
docker volume prune .
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker has a concept of a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  By default the storage for this lives somewhere on your host system and you can't directly access it from outside Docker (*).  A named volume has its own lifecycle, it can be independently [`docker volume rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_rm/)'d, and if you start another container mounting the same volume, it will have the same persistent content.

The `docker run -v` option takes some unit of storage, either a named volume or a specific host directory, and mounts it (as in the **mount**(8) command) in a specific place in the container filesystem.  This will hide what was originally in the image and replace it with the volume content.

As you note, if the thing you mount is an empty named volume, it will get populated from the image content at container initialization time.  There are some really important caveats on this functionality:

- Named volume initialization happens **only if the volume is totally empty**.
- The contents of the named volume **never automatically update**.
- If the volume isn't empty, the volume contents **completely replace what's in the image**, even if it's changed.
- The initialization happens **only on native Docker**, and not for example in Kubernetes.
- The initialization happens **only on named volumes**, and not for bind-mounted host directories.

With all of these caveats, I'd avoid relying on this functionality.

If you need to mount a volume into a container, assume it will be empty when your entrypoint or the main container command starts.  If you need a particular directory layout or file structure there, an entrypoint script can create it; if you're expecting it to hold particular data, keep a copy of it somewhere else in your image and copy it in if it's not already there (or, perhaps, always).

(*) On native Linux you can find a filesystem location for it, but accessing this isn't a best practice.  On other OSes this will be hidden inside a virtual machine or other opaque storage.  If you need to directly access the data (or inject config files, or read log files) a `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path` [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) is a better choice.